# GeoExt WMS GetFeatureInfo in proxy server. Problem - popup is empty in chrome and not responding in firefox?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geoext, proxy

- I have python2.7 and apache installed in my computer.
- In proxy.cgi, I included in topline :

  > #!/usr/bin/env python.exe -u;
- I also added 'localhost:8080/geoserver' and 'localhost:80 in allowedhosts.
- I moved the OpenLayers files to htdocs folder of apache.
- I copied the cgi file to apche/cgi-bin.
- Now, when I click on feature, popup appears but is empty.

Please help!! where my code went wrong?
Given below is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/recipes/resources/ext/ext-all.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/recipes/resources/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/recipes/resources/ext/resources/css/xtheme-gray.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/recipes/resources/openlayers/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/recipes/resources/app/theme/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/recipes/resources/geoext/resources/css/gxtheme-gray.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/recipes/resources/openlayers/build/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/recipes/resources/geoext/build/GeoExt.js"></script>
    <script>
        OpenLayers.ImgPath = "http://localhost:8080/recipes/resources/openlayers/img/";

        // the `panel` and `popup` variables are declared here for easy debugging
        var panel, popup;

        Ext.onReady(function() {
        OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";    
            // queryable WMS layer
            var zoning = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "railroads",
                "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/usa/wms",
                {layers: "usa:states", format: "image/gif", transparent: "true"}
            );

            panel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
                title: "MapPanel",
                renderTo: "map-id",
                height: 300,
                width: "100%",
                layers: [
                    new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                        "Global Imagery",
                        "http://maps.opengeo.org/geowebcache/service/wms",
                        {layers: "openstreetmap", format: "image/png"}
                    ), 
                    zoning
                ],
                center: [-122.87, 42.34],
                zoom: 13
            });

            // create a control to get feature info from queryable layers
            var control = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/usa/wms"
                title: 'Identify features by clicking',
                layers: [zoning],
            });
            panel.map.addControl(control);
            control.activate();

            // register a listener for the getfeatureinfo event on the control
            control.events.on({
                getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                    // close existing popup
                    if (popup) {
                        popup.destroy();
                    }
                    popup = new GeoExt.Popup({
                        title: "Popup",
                        map: panel.map,
                        lonlat: panel.map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                        width: 250,
                        autoScroll: true,
                        collapsible: true,
                        bodyStyle: {padding: 5},
                        html: event.text
                    });
                    popup.show();
                }
            });

        });

    </script>
```

[image]

After changing the path to wamp/www and still I am getting this new following error:

[image]

Comment: What does the console show in firebug or chrome?  Does it contain any error?

Comment: Additionally, have you confirmed that the proxy is working?

Comment: I am getting this error in console in chrome when I click on the feature : XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fgeoserver%…D469%26y%3D118%26height%3D273%26width%3D1304%26info_format%3Dtext%252Fhtml. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. OpenLayers.js:1081
cXMLHttpRequest.send OpenLayers.js:1081
(anonymous function) OpenLayers.js:867
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 OpenLayers.js:1081
cXMLHttpRequest.send OpenLayers.js:1081
(anonymous function) OpenLayers.js:867

Comment: You have installed WAMP and have placed your html file there. Why then are you accessing it using the file protocol? Access it using the http Prootocol. SOmething like http://localhost/featureinfo.html. (One more problem is is that if you have installed Wamp, your HTML/Javascript files should be in C:\Wamp\www and not C:\Wamp\bin\Apache\htdocs)

Comment: Yes thankyou!! it worked. but still there is problem. Now popup shows an error instead of being empty like before. I will attach the new snapshot

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe hey! I am stuck here!! please help! I am still getting error..this time it is popup is not empty but showing internal service error. this is the url : http://115.241.55.138/jeevan.html please check once!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 500 error indicates that the server is having problems. This tells me that the proxy is not configured properly.

To solve the issue, I would check the following:

1. Are you on a Linux/Unix Machine? The path `#!/usr/bin/env python.exe -u;` is usually for linux systems. My proxy file on a windows machine has the following as the first line: `#!C:/Python27/Python.exe -u`
2. You need to add the external IP/domain name in the allowedHosts. so it should not be `localahost:8080` but `115.241.55.138:8080`
3. You need to check the logs of your web-server for any other errors.
4. You need to confirm that the proxy is in fact working. If you are using the OpenLayers Proxy,  just visit the proxy at `http:\\115.241.55.138\cgi-bin\proxy.cgi` and see if the OpenLayers Website comes up.

Comment: no..I did the first 2 steps. I dont know how to anything regarding the configuration of web-server..help!!

Comment: I changed the path to #!C:\Python25\python.exe -u and also my present ip address. but when I visit the proxy, it is showing internal service error.

Comment: Look in your web server logs. You will get the detailed error there.